# Why $\varphi(r) = r^2$ is not a radial basis function?

Tags: functions

I was reading wikipedia article about [Radial Basis Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function). I found the following example in that article:

> $\varphi (r)=r^{2}$ in $V=\mathbb {R}$ is not a radial basis function

Since, I have no good mathematical background, I couldn't see why it is not.

Could you please explain me why that function is not a radial basis function?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article says that for any $\{\mathbf{x}_{k}\}_{k=1}^{n}$, the functions $\varphi_{\mathbf{x}_{k}}\equiv\varphi(\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_{k}\|)$ must be linearly independent. However, this is not the case for $\varphi(r)=r^{2}$, as
$$2\varphi(|r-1|)-2\varphi(|r+1|)-\varphi(|r-2|)+\varphi(|r+2|)=0$$
for all $r$.

Comment: What about any even exponent, that is: $r^k$ where $k=4, 6, 8, \cdots$? is it possible to prove that all these function are not RBFs?

Comment: Maybe a stupid question but I cannot figure out why the criteria "linearly independent". Could you explain that?